# How to get intellisense for extracted variables?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

### The problem

I'm trying to refactor some of my code in [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) by extracting an argument of a function to a global constant. However, once I do this I lose the ability to use [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense) when editing that object!

### Some examples

Really I want this functionality with tools and libraries I'm not familiar with, but for simplicity, I made a simple example below to demonstrate what I'm referring to.

**Example with intellisense**

[image: Example with intellisense]

**Example where the extracted object doesn't have intellisense**

[image: Extracted example without intellisense]

**Example for testing**

```js
/**
 * Example to test intellisense
 * @param {Object} person 
 * @param {string} person.first 
 * @param {string} person.last 
 */
function sayName(person) {
  console.log(person.first, person.last);
}

// Intellisense works here! 
sayName({first: "Robert", last: "Todar"});

// Intellisense doesn't work here.. ☹
const person = {
  first: "Robert",
  last: "Todar"
}
sayName(person);
```

---

### The question

Is there any way of getting intellisense when I've extracted an argument from a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use [@typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) that will act like a `Global Definition` then, you'll need to add [@type](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) or [@param](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) on **top of every new objects | functions**.

**Syntax will look like this:**

```js
/**
 * @typedef {object} person creates a new type 'object' named 'person'
 * @property {string} first - a 'string' property of 'person'
 * @property {string} last - a another 'string' property of 'person'
 * @property {number} [age] - an optional 'number' property of 'person'
 */
```

For **Functions** add `/** @param {person} name */` This will tell IntelliSense that **name** parameter  is referring to person object **properties**. (`@arg`,`@argument` works too)

```js
/** @param {person} name */
function sayName(name) {
    // IntelliSense works here
    console.log(name.first, name.last)
}

// and here too
sayName({})
```

[image]

---

As for **Objects:** add `/** @type person */` which will tell IntelliSense that **john** object is same as **person** object.

```js
/** @type person */
const john = {}
```

[image]

---

- [JSDoc Comments for JavaScript IntelliSense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-jsdoc-comments-for-javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2015)
- [TypeScript supported jsdoc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#supported-jsdoc)
- [Some useful examples](https://cheatsheets.joshuatz.com/settings/vscode/)